# Symfony 4 + Sonata Admin - No metadata found for property in inherited property

Tags: symfony, symfony4, sonata-admin

I've got an error for some time now when I try to add filters to an Admin.
There are two entities: **Client** and **Order**.

In the `OrderAdmin` file, the following filters work:

```
$datagridMapper
    ->add('id')
    ->add('client.email')
    ->add('client.id')
;
```

But if I add this line `->add('client.name')` it triggers this error:

> No metadata found for property `App\Entity\Order::$client.name.
>   Please make sure your Doctrine mapping is properly configured.

The **Client** entity is inherited by two others entities. Both of them contain the property name.
While the id and email are both present in the parent entity. I'm guessing this is why the error appears:

```
* @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"user_1" = "one", "user_2" = "two"})
```

This used to work fine on previous versions.
Any idea of how to solve the problem? (Transferring the name property to the parent class isn't really a solution for me).

EDIT : the Order class

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

/**
 * Order
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Order")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OrderRepository")
 */
class Order
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    private $amount;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="state", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
     */
    private $state;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Client")
    */
    private $client;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Article", mappedBy="order", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
    */
    private $articles;
```

bundles.php

```php
<?php

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Sonata\DatagridBundle\SonataDatagridBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\KnpSnappyBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

Comment: Can you show us your bundles.php file and your entity ?

Comment: Can you show us your Order entity?

Comment: @DylanKas I've updated my post, I was away last week ! Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by doing a filter callback as mentionned here : 
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/action_list.html#callback-filter

I would have liked to know what changed between versions for the code not to work anymore but maybe some other time !

Answer (score 0):

In this case this was due to class configuration. Mapping is injected during Sf DI, but this custom User Class was not found.

Just check classes used by the News Bundle.

```
sonata_news:
    class:
        post:       Application\Sonata\NewsBundle\Entity\Post
        comment:    Application\Sonata\NewsBundle\Entity\Comment
        media:      Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
        user:       My\Custom\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

Comment: I don't have sonata News Bundle